# Does positive part in subspace which is Riesz space equal positive part in the full Riesz space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-lattices

In my thesis I encountered the following problem: suppose that $E,F$ are Riesz spaces such that $E$ is a subspace of $F$ and that the ordering on $E$ matches the one on $F$, i.e. $x\leq_E y\Rightarrow x\leq_F y$ where $\leq_E$ is the ordering on $E$ and $\leq_F$ the one on $F$. My question is: for any element $x\in E$ we can define the positive part in $E$ and we can define it in $F$. Are those two elements necessarily the same?

If this is true, can we drop the condition that $E$ is Riesz and just assume that we have an element $x\in E$ for which the positive part in $E$ exists?

In most simple examples I tried I found the answer to be yes, but I could not find a proof. Has anyone here encountered a similar problem and found a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is false. Indeed, let $E$ be the Riesz space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
provided with the pointwise algebraic and lattice operations and $F=\left\{
\left( x,y,x+y\right) \text{ }/\text{ }x,y\in \mathbb{R}\right\} .$ Then $F$
, equipped with the algebraic and lattice operations inherited from $E,$ is
a Riesz space. However the positive part of $\left( x,y,x+y\right) $ in $E$
equals $\left( x^{+},y^{+},\left( x+y\right) ^{+}\right) $ and the positive
part of $\left( x,y,x+y\right) $ in $F$ equals $\left(
x^{+},y^{+},x^{+}+y^{+}\right) .$